# How to get div to fill entire screen (Masonry/Pinterest) layout

Tags: html, css, grid, pinterest, masonry

Two questions:

1) Why won't the columns in my div fill up the page (take up the white space) rather than overflowing to the next column? (Click view full page when running the code snippet.)

2) How to make the columns more responsive? (i.e., have the columns zoom in and out when I change the screen size, rather than shrinking every column to the left or stretching to the right).

```css
#container {
  /*min-height: 100vh;*/
  /*min-width: 100vw;*/
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.columns {
  -moz-column-count: 5;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
  -moz-column-width: 40%;
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
  -webkit-column-width: 40%;
  column-count: 5;
  column-gap: 1em;
  column-width: 40%;
}

.box {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.box.one {
  height: 230px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.box.two {
  height: 230px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.box.three {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 230px;
}

.box.four {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 180px;
}

.box.five {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 170px;
}

.box.six {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 180px;
}

.box.seven {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 200px;
}

.box.eight {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
}

.box.nine {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 200px;
}

.box.ten {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
}

.box.eleven {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 200px;
}

.box.twelve {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


<div id="container" class="columns">
  <div class="box one">1</div>
  <div class="box two">2</div>
  <div class="box three">3</div>
  <div class="box four">4</div>
  <div class="box five">5</div>
  <div class="box six">6</div>
  <div class="box seven">7</div>
  <div class="box eight">8</div>
  <div class="box nine">9</div>
  <div class="box ten">10</div>
  <div class="box eleven">11</div>
  <div class="box twelve">12</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make a login/landing page like Pinterest. Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/tansica/pen/wEEjqq).

I tried tinkering with max/min height/width and setting it to 100%, 100px, 100vh/vw and nothing seems to work.

What am I getting wrong? Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In terms of making it responsive depending on screen size, you need to add a media query such as:

```
@media(max-width:700px){
}
```

what that will do is detect when the screen width is 700px or less and inside you just put what you want your site to look like if in that case. So for instance, if naturally, you have a div that on a computer is half width you would do:

```
div {
    width: 50%;
}
```

then if you're on a phone screen and you wanted to make that div full width you would just add:

```
div {
    width: 50%;
}
@media(max-width:600px) {
    div {
         width: 100%;
    }
}
```

and it will change accordingly, hope this helps!

Comment: No problem, if you need any more help let me know